# how to make sure two inline elements stay on the same line

Tags: html, css

How can I make sure two inline elements stay on the same line no matter how narrow the viewport might be?

In my case an input field and a submit button (made to look like one long button you put your email into)

Comment: Can you post the code you have at the moment? Sounds like you need to set either the overflow property or the min-width property of whatever container the elements are in.

Comment: If it is only two elements, you can just give them both a width of 50% and a display of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would need to be wrapped in a parent element:

```css
.singleLineChildren {
  /* prevents the contents from wrapping to a new line: */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* prevents the overflow being seen/scrolled-to;
     adjust to taste: */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* to emphasize/speed-up the effect: */
  width: 50%;
  /* just for visibility: */
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px #f90;
}

.singleLineChildren {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* purely so that narrowing the browser screen has
     an obviously visible effect: */
  font-size: 4em;
  min-width: 5em;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="singleLineChildren">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can try this:

```css
div {
  padding:5px;
  }
.father { 
  display: block;
  }
.child {
  display:inline-block;
  }
.red {
  background: red;
  color:white;
  }
.blue {
  background: blue
    }
```

```html
<div class="father">
  
  <div class="child red">
     I am red
    </div>
  <div class="child blue">
     I am blue
    </div>
  <div class="child red">
     I am red
    </div>
  <div class="child blue">
     I am blue
    </div>
  </div>
```